# How is this possible? (Junit exception testing of linked list implementation

Tags: java, junit, linked-list

I am writing a LinkedList implementation which includes a previous function that returns the position prior to the one passed as an input argument. It should check whether the inputted position is the first one and throw an exception in that case:

```
@Override
public Position<T> previous (Position<T> p) throws PositionException {
    if (this.first(p)) {
        throw new PositionException();
    }
    return this.convert(p).prev;
}
```

However, the following test is failing because it isn't throwing the expected exception from trying to use the previous function on the first position in the array:

```
@Test (expected=PositionException.class)
public void gettingPreviousAtFront() {
    Position<String> one = list.insertFront("One");
    Position<String> two = list.insertFront("Two");
    assertTrue(list.first(two));
    Position<String> beforeTwo = list.previous(two);
}
```

> There was 1 failure: 1)
>   gettingPreviousAtFront(hw6.test.LinkedListTest)
>   java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception:
>   exceptions.PositionException at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:32)

It is even passing the assertion on line 301 of the test that "two" is first. So how is it possible that the exception is not being thrown by the previous function?

Here is the full linkedlist code:

```
package hw6;

import exceptions.EmptyException;
import exceptions.PositionException;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class LinkedList<T> implements List<T> {

    private static final class Node<T> implements Position<T> {
        // The usual doubly-linked list stuff.
        Node<T> next;   // reference to the Node after this
        Node<T> prev;   // reference to the Node before this
        T data;

        // List that created this node, to validate positions.
        List<T> owner;

        @Override
        public T get() {
            return this.data;
        }

        @Override
        public void put(T t) {
            this.data = t;
        }
    }

    /** This iterator can be used to create either a forward
        iterator, or a backwards one.
    */
    private final class ListIterator implements Iterator<T> {
        Node<T> current;
        boolean forward;

        ListIterator(boolean f) {
            this.forward = f;
            if (this.forward) {
                this.current = LinkedList.this.sentinelHead.next;
            } else {
                this.current = LinkedList.this.sentinelTail.prev;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public T next() throws NoSuchElementException {
            if (!this.hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            T t = this.current.get();
            if (this.forward) {
                this.current = this.current.next;
            } else {
                this.current = this.current.prev;
            }
            return t;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (this.forward) {
                return this.current != LinkedList.this.sentinelTail;
            }
            else {
                return this.current != LinkedList.this.sentinelHead;
            }
        }
    }

    /* ** LinkedList instance variables are declared here! ** */

    private Node<T> sentinelHead;
    private Node<T> sentinelTail;
    private int length;             // how many nodes in the list

    /**
     * Create an empty list.
     */
    public LinkedList() {
        this.sentinelHead = new Node<>();
        this.sentinelTail = new Node<>();
        this.sentinelHead.owner = this;
        this.sentinelTail.owner = this;
        this.sentinelTail.prev = this.sentinelHead;
        this.sentinelHead.next = this.sentinelTail;
        this.length = 0;
    }

    // Convert a position back into a node. Guards against null positions,
    // positions from other data structures, and positions that belong to
    // other LinkedList objects. That about covers it?
    private Node<T> convert(Position<T> p) throws PositionException {
        try {
            Node<T> n = (Node<T>) p;
            if (n.owner != this) {
                throw new PositionException();
            }
            return n;
        } catch (NullPointerException | ClassCastException e) {
            throw new PositionException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean empty() {
        return this.length == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return this.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean first(Position<T> p) throws PositionException {
        Node<T> n = this.convert(p);
        return this.sentinelHead.next == n;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean last(Position<T> p) throws PositionException {
        Node<T> n = this.convert(p);
        return this.sentinelTail.prev == n;
    }

    @Override
    public Position<T> front() throws EmptyException {
        if (this.length == 0) {
            throw new EmptyException();
        }
        return this.sentinelHead.next;
    }

    @Override
    public Position<T> back() throws EmptyException {
        if (this.empty()) {
            throw new EmptyException();
        }
        return this.sentinelTail.prev;
    }

    @Override
    public Position<T> next(Position<T> p) throws PositionException {
        if (this.last(p)) {
            throw new PositionException();
        }
        return this.convert(p).next;
    }

    @Override
    public Position<T> previous(Position<T> p) throws PositionException {
        if (this.first(p)) {
            throw new PositionException();
        }
        return this.convert(p).prev;
    }

    @Override
    public Position<T> insertFront(T t) {
        return this.insertAfter(this.sentinelHead, t);
    }

    @Override
    public Position<T> insertBack(T t) {
        return this.insertBefore(this.sentinelTail, t);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeFront() throws EmptyException {
        this.remove(this.front());
    }

    @Override
    public void removeBack() throws EmptyException {
        this.remove(this.back());
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Position<T> p) throws PositionException {
        Node<T> n = this.convert(p);
        n.owner = null;
        n.prev.next = n.next;
        n.next.prev = n.prev;
        this.length--;
    }

    @Override
    public Position<T> insertBefore(Position<T> p, T t)
            throws PositionException {
        Node<T> current = this.convert(p);
        Node<T> n = new Node<T>();
        n.owner = this;
        n.data = t;

        n.prev = current.prev;
        current.prev.next = n;
        n.next = current;
        current.prev = n;
        this.length++;
        return n;
    }

    @Override
    public Position<T> insertAfter(Position<T> p, T t)
            throws PositionException {
        Node<T> current = this.convert(p);
        Node<T> n = new Node<T>();
        n.owner = this;
        n.data = t;

        n.next = current.next;
        current.next.prev = n;
        n.prev = current;
        current.next = n;
        this.length++;
        return n;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> forward() {
        return new ListIterator(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> backward() {
        return new ListIterator(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return this.forward();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.append("[");
        for (Node<T> n = this.sentinelHead.next; n != this.sentinelTail; n = n.next) {
            s.append(n.data);
            if (n.next != this.sentinelTail) {
                s.append(", ");
            }
        }
        s.append("]");
        return s.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if You could paste the full code instead of images. Can You paste methods: `first` and `instertFront`?

Comment: [Don't post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), instead post them in your question as formatted text. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue. For more information about Stack Overflow and asking questions, take the [tour], read [ask], and visit the [help].